# Why does the phenomenon of localized energy producing particles and antiparticles lead to the creation of an infinite number of particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy

Penrose says the following (paraphrased) in "Road to Reality" on pg 611 of the first American edition

> A particle and anti particle may combine to produce energy, as given by general relativity. Moreover, energy, if sufficiently localized, may produce a particle and an anti particle. Hence, in attempting to come up with a theory of relativistic particles, one is driven to a theory in which there is a potential for the creation of an infinite number of particles.

How can this be true, if the total energy in the universe is finite, and hence can only produce a finite number of particles.

Comment: The question shouldn't be "How can this be true?" The question should be "What is Penrose trying to say?" I haven't read *Road to Reality*, and maybe the context clarifies things, but just based on the paraphrased excerpt, this looks to me like a word salad.

Comment: I think what Penrose is trying to say is that if you unite special relativity and quantum mechanics, you get a theory which has the feature that one can create more and more particles if you keep pumping more and more energy within a sufficiently localized region. This is a profound statement about the fundamental nature of matter and energy.